# Move all the Files generated 23 hrs. after they were first created

Tags: shell

I am using below command to pick the files  23 hrs after they were first created, but it is not picking can you tell me where i am going wrong

```
find /test/files -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +0.9
```

`mtime +1` means 24 hours later
so, used `+0.9` so it should pick 23 hours , but it is not picking.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid fractions will not work in `find`. What you can do is to create file with timestamp 23 hours ago and with `find` get older files:

```
touch -d '23 hours ago' /tmp/tmp_file 
find /test/files -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -newer /tmp/tmp_file
```

Comment: i tried touch but 23 hours is not working , can i use mmin 13800 for 23 hours

Comment: What is your OS, this work fine on linux

Comment: And if you want it in minutes is 1380